# Как из php вернуть конкретную переменную?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

В ajax success из php не возвращается `echo "1";`. Точнее, если закомментировать строку `$mail->send();` - то возвращается "1", иначе видимо пытается вернуться результат `$mail->send();` 
Как вернуть именно `echo "1";`, а не `$mail->send();`?

```
<?
   if ($error == "no") {

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //Настройки сервера
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.oo-gsi.ru';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Username = '***';
    $mail->Password = '***';
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 25;

    //Получатели
    $mail->setFrom('admin@oo-gsi.ru', 'Сайт ГСИ');
    $mail->addAddress('sbrujg@mail.ru', 'Охранная огранизация ГСИ');

    //Вложения
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $file_name = cyrillic_translit($file['name']);
        $mail->addAttachment("$uploaddir/$file_name");
    }

    //Содержание
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Анкета для приема на работу';

    $mail->Body = 
        'Новая анкета для приема на работу в охранную организацию «ГСИ». <br><br>ФИО: '.rec($_POST['posName']).' <br>Телефон: '.rec($_POST['posPhone']).' <br>Email-адрес: '.rec($_POST['posEmail']).' <br>Год рождения: '.rec($_POST['posBirthday']).' <br>Гражданство: '.rec($_POST['posCitizenship']).' <br>Город проживания: '.rec($_POST['posCity']).' <br>Готовность к командировкам: '.rec($_POST['posMove']).' <br>Опыт работы в охранной сфере: '.rec($_POST['posExperience']).'';

    $mail->AltBody = 
        'Новая анкета для приема на работу в охранную организацию «ГСИ». //ФИО: '.rec($_POST['posName']).' /Телефон: '.rec($_POST['posPhone']).' /Email-адрес: '.rec($_POST['posEmail']).' /Год рождения: '.rec($_POST['posBirthday']).' /Гражданство: '.rec($_POST['posCitizenship']).' /Город проживания: '.rec($_POST['posCity']).' /Готовность к командировкам: '.rec($_POST['posMove']).' /Опыт работы в охранной сфере: '.rec($_POST['posExperience']).'';

    $mail->send();

    echo "1";
} else { //Если есть ошибки
    echo "0";
}
?>
```

Comment: Видимо ошибка с mail

Comment: Нет, ошибки нет - письмо отправляется и приходит. Просто он воспринимается как ответ. Как можно обойти это место?

Comment: if($mail->send()){ Отправлено} else{Не отправлено}

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php
Исходя из исходного кода send() должен возвращает boolean

В Вашем случаае скорее всего $mail->send(); возвращает ошибку. Вы проверяли?

Comment: send() возвращает весь свой лог, это если в `dataType : "text"`, а так ничего не возвращает в `dataType : "json"`

Comment: `if($mail->send()){ Отправлено} else{Не отправлено}`  не работает

Comment: Можно ли отключить логи у `$mail->send()`?

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

Comment: Всем спасибо. С `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` работает как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас включен логирование. Отключите лог:

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

 if($mail->send()){
     echo "1";
 {
```